# Regex: find whole pattern, replace partially

Tags: .net, regex, replace, substring

I have to find strings like:

```
"^some_text/some_number$"
```

for example:

```
"thetext/34526435"
```

and if `some_text` is "generic" then take the number after slash, replacing "generic" to an empty string, otherwise take `some_text` replacing the number and the slash to an empty string.

Is this possible with one regular expression?

I am using `Regex.Replace` from Microsoft.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, yes.

C# regexes have something called a MatchEvaluator. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx

The MatchEvaluator will be called for every match, asking it what it should do with the values it found. Whatever it decides will be replaced into the string, so you can have different replacement logic based off of the values.

Answer (score 0):

In python, yes.

The `re` module has a function calles `sub` that replaces all occurrences of the regex *pattern* in *string* with *repl* like

```
sub(pattern,repl, string)
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state how the input is like, so you might have to adapt the following piece of code. You also didn't state how the text portion is like, so I just use `[a-zA-Z]` as a guide. Feel free to change to however method you use to check that it's a valid text portion (like `\w` or something).

The return value of the delegate might seem terse, but from the way the question was phrased, it feels like there shouldn't be too many lines of code or something. Feel free to expand with if statements and whatnot.

```
string sInput = "generic/1234";
string sOutput = Regex.Replace(sInput, "^(?<mytext>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?<mynum>\\d+)$", delegate(Match m)
{
    return m.Groups["mytext"].Value.Equals("generic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? m.Groups["mynum"].Value : m.Groups["mytext"].Value;
});
```

You mentioned that if the text portion is "generic" you take the number, but you didn't say whether the slash should still be included.

Also, the code only works on the specific "text/number" pattern. It will return the original string if the original string doesn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `^(generic/([0-9]+)|([a-z]+)/[0-9]+)$` by `$2$3` ([demo](http://regexr.com?35574)).